# Saco la Data de una API y me regresa UNDIFINED

Tags: javascript, axios, async

Este de abajo es mi controlador con el que mando a llamar la info de la api
al momento de llamarla con insomnia (http://localhost:3001/pokemons) me regresa undifined y deberia regresarme un a matriz de objetos o arreglo de objetos [{...},{...},...]

````
const axios = require("axios");

const getPokemonData = async () => {
  try {
    let i = 1;
    let pokemons = []

    while (i < 1282) {
      let apiData = await axios(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}/`)
      pokemons.push(apiData);
      i++;
    }
    pokemons = (await Promise.all(pokemons)).map((res) =>
      res.data.map((poke) => {

        const stat = (stat) => {
          poke.stats.map((pokeStat) => {
            if (pokeStat.name == stat) {
              return pokeStat.base_stat;
            }
            console.log(poke.stats);
          });
        };

        return {
          id: poke.id,
          name: poke.name,
          image: poke.sprites.front_default,
          health: stat(hp),
          attack: stat(attack),
          defend: stat(defense),
          speed: stat(speed),
          height: poke.height,
          weight: poke.weight,
        };
      })
    );
    let allPokemons = [];
    pokemons.map(poke => {allPokemons = allPokemons.concat(poke)})
    return allPokemons;
  } catch (error) {
    return { error: error.message };
  }
};

module.exports = getPokemonData;

Y  aqui seguido es como mando a llamar al controlador
router.get("/pokemons", async(req, res) => {
    console.log(await getPokemonData)
  res.status(200).json(await getPokemonData);
});```
````

llevo un rato intentando resolverlo, pense que seria lo dle asyc await pero tampoco
Agradesco su ayuda de antemano

Comment: No es "undifined", es `undefined`. Por cierto, debes estudiar la sintaxis de `async await`. ¿Dónde están los `then()`? Fijate los ejemplos en [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises).

Comment: no uso then() ya que no use fetch() si no axios, y la response la tengo en las rutas que fue lo que puse abajo, igual dejame leo el MDN

Comment: Lo que mencionás es dentro de _getPokemonData_. De mi parte, hacía referencia a `console.log(await getPokemonData)`.

Comment: [Igual se usa `then()`](https://axios-http.com/es/docs/res_schema) :) No olvides revisar siempre la documentación.

Comment: ¿Has probado a llamar a la función? Independientemente de los fallos de lógica al usar `axios`, no estás llamando realmente a la función `getPokemonData`. Deberías usar los paréntesis: `await getPokemonData()`. Saludos

Comment: Una disculpa por mi desinformacion apenas ando aprendiendo, Al principio si la llame ocmo funcion usando parentesis al final, pero me salia "TypeError: getPokemonData is not a function" por eso lo cambie, dejame lo pongo como funcion y reviso mas a detalle por que me aparecera eso y leere la documentacion del .then()
Ya de ahi almenos ya tengo donde partir para buscar soluciones

Comment: Hola mauricio, cuadno llamo con parentesis me sale un error que dice que que getPokemonData no es una funcion